# Powershell - remove 20 characters from each line

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with several lines:

```
9 1/7/20 11:46:25 am PC-OCWIN0306 Device status is Critical. Protection is off.

10 1/7/20 11:10:16 am PC-OCWIN0277 Device status is Critical. Protection is off; Security application is not running.

11 1/7/20 2:47:19 pm LT-FRWIN0004 Device status is Critical. Security application is not installed.
```

I would like to remove the first 20 characters from each line, so it looks something like:

```
PC-OCWIN0306 Device status is Critical. Protection is off.
PC-OCWIN0277 Device status is Critical. Protection is off; Security application is not running.
LT-FRWIN0004 Device status is Critical. Security application is not installed.
```

I have been trying to use this:

```
$testfile = Get-Content -Path "Z:\IT Users\Username\test.txt"
foreach($line in $testfile) {
    $line.TrimStart(20)
    }
}
Out-File "Z:\IT Users\Username\trimtest.txt"
pause
```

but it's not doing what I want.

Comment: When asking questions work from your desktop.  Do not use `Z:\IT Users\Username\test.txt` use `%userprofile%\desktop\test.txt` and since this is a powershell question use powershell variables, not `%userprofile%\desktop\test.txt` but `$env:userprofile\desktop\test.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5

Edit text file from the command line with PowerShell and regular expressions.

Remove, by replacing with nothing, from the beginning of line up to and including pattern "m ".  Remove extra carriage return and extra line feed (change double line spacing to single line spacing).

```
$source  = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\2.txt" 
$trim = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\3.txt" 
(Get-Content $source -Raw) -replace "^.|.*m " -replace "[`r`n]+", "`n" | Set-Content $trim
```

[Raw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50295912/8826818), carriage return and new line explanation at stackoverflow

- By default, get-content automatically splits a file into lines on
  newlines. You need to use the -raw parameter to read the file as a
  single block of text.

Go to https://regex101.com to test your regular expressions and get explanations for how they work. For this method of replacement I found the Tool - Code Generator - Language - AutoIt to be informative.

Regular expression: `^.|.*m` **Do not forget the space after m.** From the beginning of line match everything up to and including pattern "m ".

Regular expression: `(?m) D.*.$` Match everything after " D" except carriage returns and line feeds.

Regular expression: `[\r\n]+` Change double line spacing to single line spacing.

Test file / string:

```
9 1/7/20 11:46:25 am PC-OCWIN0306 Device status is Critical. Protection is off.

10 1/7/20 11:10:16 am PC-OCWIN0277 Device status is Critical. Protection is off; Security application is not running.

11 1/7/20 2:47:19 pm LT-FRWIN0004 Device status is Critical. Security application is not installed.
```

Results:

```
PC-OCWIN0306 Device status is Critical. Protection is off.    
PC-OCWIN0277 Device status is Critical. Protection is off; Security application is not running.    
LT-FRWIN0004 Device status is Critical. Security application is not installed.
```

Replace everything except the device name:

```
$source  = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\2.txt" 
$trim = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\3.txt" 
(Get-Content $source -Raw) -replace "^.|.*m " -replace "(?m) D.*.$" -replace "[`r`n]+", "`n" | Set-Content $trim
```

Results:

```
PC-OCWIN0306
PC-OCWIN0277
LT-FRWIN0004
```

Thanks to https://regex101.com/ for the screenshots.

[image: screenshot of regex ^.|.*m]

[image: screenshot of regex (?m) D.*.$]

[image: screenshot of regex \r\n]

^.|.*m

- Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «^.»

  - Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
  - Match any single character that is not a line break character «.»
- Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «.*m »

  - Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»

    - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
  - Match the characters "m " literally «m »

(?m) D.*.$

- Match the remainder of the regex with the options: ^ and $ match at line breaks (m)

  Match the characters " D" literally

  Match any single character that is not a line break character

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

  Match any single character that is not a line break character

  Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)

[\r\n]+

- Match a single character present in the list below

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

    A carriage return character

    A line feed character (new line)

Edit text file with PS and Regex. Edit text file with PowerShell and Regex. Edit text file with PowerShell and regular expression.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Could you elaborate on the + in "[`r`n]+". I understand the code aside from that.

Comment: @roc not %username% but $env:username.  See updated answer.  my link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50295912/8826818 explains +.  If you need more regex explanation see updated answer.

Comment: The "username" was just to get rid of personally identifiable information (PII). i.e. my name. I wasn't trying to add any variables or anything lol, but thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: @roc not %username% but $env:username has nothing to do with username.  It is to notify you that I have corrected an error in my code.  When you want to hide your username use %username%

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: Guidance on how to match from the "-" to the end of the line so I only get the "PC-OCWIN0306" part of each line back? I tried "^.|.*-" to match the "-" but that doesn't work. I also tried "$" to start at the end of the line but no luck with that either.

Comment: @roc results "PC-OCWIN0306"

Comment: @pim are you talking about the regex explanations screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Remove](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8) method.

```
$testfile = Get-Content -Path "Z:\IT Users\Username\test.txt"
foreach($line in $testfile) {
    $line.Remove(0,20)
    }
} | Out-File "Z:\IT Users\Username\trimtest.txt"
```

or avoid intermediate variables:

```
Get-Content -Path "Z:\IT Users\Username\test.txt" | ForEach{
   $_.Remove(0,20)
} | Out-File "Z:\IT Users\Username\trimtest.txt"
```

Edit: I took you at your word regarding 20 characters, but see the length of the Date/Time can vary, and if so a regex is your best bet. Does your imput file actually contain blank lines between each line with text? If not, the following regex should do the trick, and it's easier to see what it's captruing:

```
Get-Content $source | ForEach{$_ -replace '^.+m ' -replace ' Device.+$'}
```

Comment: I understand what's going on here, but it doesn't output any file..., don't know why.

Comment: If you eliminate the pipe to `Out-File`, do you get output on the console?

Comment: I'm getting this error "Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist." The Z drive is a networked drive, and I've used it in this script ```$source = "Z:\IT Users\On-Call KAS Critical Host Status PS\input.txt"
$final = "Z:\IT Users\On-Call KAS Critical Host Status PS\Name - Issue output.txt"
(Get-Content $source -Raw) -replace "^.|.*m " -replace "[`r`n]+", "`n" -replace "Device status is Critical.", "-" | Set-Content $final``` and it will output fine, so I'm confused what the difference is...

Comment: I figured it out, had to put the Get-Content in parentheses so it would load the file first.  ```$source = "Z:\IT Users\On-Call KAS Critical Host Status PS\name_issue_output.txt"
(Get-Content $source) | ForEach{
   $_.Remove(14)
} | Out-File "Z:\IT Users\On-Call KAS Critical Host Status PS\name_only.txt"```

Comment: That's very odd. Just re-tested and no parentheses needed regardless of whether the filename is in a variable or in-line.

Comment: You have `Remove(14)`, which removes everything _after_ the 14th character. `Remove(0,14)` trims the beginning.

Comment: @Kmiller Yep I wanted everything after the 14th character gone, I used your code (with some edits) on a different part of my script. Thanks!